# Does optimal input distribution for $W^{\otimes n}_{Y|X}$ tell us anything about the optimal input distribution for $W^{\otimes n-1}_{Y|X}$?

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory

Suppose I have $n$ i.i.d. copies of some channel $W_{Y|X}$ for some finite $n$. I wish to send the maximum number of messages over these $n$ copies such that the error in decoding the message is at most $\varepsilon$. There is some encoder and decoder that I use. Let such an encoder result in some input distribution $p_{X^n}$ to the channels.

Now, suppose I only had $(n-1)$ copies of the channel $W_{Y|X}$. There again exists some optimal input distribution $p_{X^{n-1}}$.

Are $p_{X^{n-1}}$ and $p_{X^{n}}$ related? In particular, can one obtain $p_{X^{n-1}}$ as a marginal distribution of $p_{X^{n}}$?